# Still not added to the DOM but if and alert/confirm inserted get the tag ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of jquery/javascript and i don't understand why this is happend and how should i fixed it.
 The tag with the id="group_"+num is loaded with ajax so it seem not being added to the DOM yet , the funny part is if i put one alert in the middle the function works, without that alert nothing happend , ¿ anyone could explain what alert does there and what should i do to get that id in the DOM so jquery could count the length as 1 ?
Of course if i get any other id not loaded with ajax , works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var num = hash.replace("#subcat_group_","");
    $('[id*="subcat_group_"]').hide();

            // here the "id" loaded with ajax seems still not loaded.
    var len = $("#group_"+num).length;
           //Here variable "len" still 0 

           /***** with this alert works , just an alert anything inside

           alert(num);

           with this alert works *****/ 

          /*******if i use "len" here still 0 even if alert is before *******/
           if( $("#group_"+num).length === 1){


          /******if i get again for id lenght with alert before , then is 1 ******/              
        if( $("#group_"+num).length === 1){
        var group_name = $("#group_"+num).attr("title");
        swapContentV1(num,group_name);
    }
    $("#subcat_group_"+num).show();
    });

});
```

thanks.

Comment: **ok and where is your ajax function ??** and most important why do you have two `document.ready` function . `$(document).ready(function(){` and `$(function(){` is same...

Comment: If you put an alert, it works because by the time you click OK on your alert, the ajax call has been completed. I would suggest you should move your code to 'success' in ajax call

Comment: sounds like an async problem and you may need to add some callbacks or put your code inside the ajax complete function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert forces the script to wait ... for your response AND for the Ajax call to be completed. Without alert you look 'too early' - Ajax is not finished then.

You should put your code into the success function, as shoogle suggested in his comment.